# Get firebase data (with or without vuefire) using a parameter from router before DOM renders in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database, vuefire

I am navigating into a view from another view and passing the itemdId as param value to vue router.

I want to be able to call firebase with that itemId so that I can filter the data and the filtered result/data is used in the UI. I am using `vuefire`.

What is happening is that vue starts rendering before the data is available in created() and I see error is the console saying view is referring to undefined property values.

Is there a way to render the view after the data is available?

I have tried the using `beforeMount` as well as `created` and `beforeCreate` approaches.

See code below:

```
<h1>{{projects[0].project_name}}</h1> //it says type error. cannot read property project_name of undefined. Sometimes on refresh it works but most times it does not.
```

Script code below:

```
    let projectsRef = db.ref('projects');
    export default {
        name: 'ProjectDetailsOpenInvesting',
        props: {
          data: Object
    },
    firebase:{
      projects: projectsRef
    },
    data(){
      return {
        projects:[],
        .....

      }
    },
    created(){
      var that = this;
      console.log(this.$route.params.itemid) //this works
      this.projects = this.projects.filter(function(p){
        return p.project_id == that.$route.params.itemid //this works as well
      })
    }
```

[Firebase screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4FEy.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have mentioned, one approach is to [fetch after navigation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/data-fetching.html#fetching-after-navigation), i.e. fetch the data in the component's `created` hook.

To do that with `vuefire` you need to programatically bind the Realtime Database `projectsRef` [`Reference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference) to the `projects` property in your Vue application, as follows:

```
created(){
  console.log(this.$route.params.itemid)
  const itemId = this.$route.params.itemid;
  this.$rtdbBind('projects', projectsRef.orderByKey().equalTo(itemId)).then(projects => {
     this.projects === projects;
  });
}
```

As explained in the [API doc](https://vuefire.vuejs.org/api/vuefire.html#rtdbbind):

> $rtdbBind returns a Promise that is resolved once the data has been
>   retrieved and synced into the state.

Note that you need to install the `rtdbPlugin` plugin: https://vuefire.vuejs.org/api/vuefire.html#rtdbplugin

---

Also note that instead of filtering the desired `project` item in the front-end (with `filter(function(p){return p.project_id == that.$route.params.itemid}))`), we filter it in the back-end, at the level of the database (`projectsRef.orderByKey().equalTo(itemId)`) which is more efficient and which avoids transmitting the entire set of objects from the back-end to the front-end (and avoids paying for this downloaded volume, see https://firebase.google.com/pricing?authuser=0).

Comment: Thanks Renaud. dumb ques: so how do I access the data from projects? I tried projects.project_name as well as projects[0].project_name both return undefined. If I do a console.log(projects) ; I see a firebase object I think. How can I access the values of this filtered object?

Comment: `{{projects[0].project_name}}` should work. If it doesn't add a printscreen of your database to your question.

Comment: Just added the screenshot link to the question.

Comment: So if the value of the query string parameter `itemid` is for example `12345`  (meaning that `console.log(this.$route.params.itemid)` should output `12345`) you should indeed do `{{projects[0].project_name}}`

Comment: Yes, `itemid` corresponds to `project_id` 12345 in the screenshot. Let me debug and see what I am doing wrong. Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: The current code will look for the node `12345` (the one right under the root `projects` node) not for the project with `project_id` = 12345. In your case they have the same value but it is important that you understand what the query `projectsRef.orderByKey().equalTo(itemId)` returns.

Comment: So to search by project_id is this the right way:

`this.$rtdbBind('projects', projectsRef.orderByChild('project_id')
            .equalTo(itemid)).then(projects => {
              this.projects === projects;
          });`

Comment: Yes, still says undefined :(( It works if I enter the key value in orderByKey manually but in my router param, i am receiving project_id value, not the key, so need to find a way to get either the key from previous view or get child level filtering.

Comment: `this.$rtdbBind('projects', projectsRef.orderByChild('project_id').equalTo(itemid))`is indeed correct. You have probably seen the documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sort_data

Comment: I am in this silly problem. If I hardcode `itemid` value, this works for me, if I pass it as a variable, its saying undefined.. Inside my `created()` function: Is there something I am missing here?

`var itemid = this.$route.params.itemid;` followed by `this.$rtdbBind('projects', projectsRef.orderByChild('project_id')
            .equalTo(itemid)).then(projects => {....`

Comment: I think I know what is the problem: the value you get via the query string (`this.$route.params.itemid`) is a string, while the `project_id` is a number in the database. You need to use `parseInt()` as follows: `var itemid = parseInt(this.$route.params.itemid, 10)`

Comment: That worked. Thanks a lot. Route look like this: `{
      path: '/booked/:itemid',
      name: 'ProjectDetailsBooked',
      component: ProjectDetailsBooked,
      props: true,
      meta: {
        menuIndex: '1',
        showTopHeader: true,
        hideFooter: false
      }
    }`  and I am passing itemId from one view to the other like this: `router.push({name: 'ProjectDetailsBooked', params: {itemid: this.data.project_id}});`